# Encode file content to Shift-JIS

Tags: apex

We use APEX to generate a file and upload it to cloud storage. But one of the file's requirements is it needs to be encoded in Shift-JIS.

Found some encoding method from `EncodingUtil` class but it seems that it is used for URLs

```
String encoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(input, 'Shift-JIS');
```

Is there any way to encode String or Blob data type in specific charset in APEX?

Thanks!

Comment: This is likely not what you are hoping for but I do not know of a way to encode into Shift-JIS using native Apex. Could you possibly call an external endpoint to do the encoding for you?